# How to install older version of GCC for Mex compatibility with Matlab on OpenSUSE?

Tags: opensuse, gcc

[Matlab MEX](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/index.html?sec=glnxa64#matlab) is compatible just with GCC version 4.7.X, however OpenSUSE 13.1 comes with GCC 4.8.1, when I compile a Matlab MEX file a warning comes out: `Warning: You are using gcc version '4.8.1'. The version of gcc is not supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'.`, and MEX compilation fails.

I saw this question in stackoverflow: [Installing older version of gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854752/installing-older-version-of-gcc), but OpenSUSE does not provide a repository with GCC older versions. How can I install easily an older version of GCC just for Matlab? And, how can I setup Matlab to do it correctly?

I'm using Matlab 8.3 R2014a.

Comment: Visit the [OpenSUSE GCC Repository](http://software.opensuse.org/package/gcc47)

Comment: @ECarterYoung I tried to install `gcc47` from that repository but installation fails.

Comment: What is the failure, as mixing a binary based distro with source based packages is generally a bad idea?

Comment: @ECarterYoung Yast just said `No se han podido instalar los siguientes paquetes: gcc47`, is in Spanish.

Comment: That translates to Not able to install the following packages: gcc4.7.  Here is the direct link from the [12.3 repo](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/12.3/repo/oss/suse/x86_64/gcc-4.7-7.1.1.x86_64.rpm)  Does it still complain?

Comment: @ECarterYoung If I install that rmp package, can affect the current installation of gcc?

Comment: @OSjerick - yes, you'll likely need to downgrade to this one.

Comment: @slm I've read that can damage the system.

Comment: @OSjerick - sorry I wasn't suggesting to do that, just that you'd have to downgrade if you wanted to use that. But I agree, you generally do not want to drop and/or mess with your gcc installation. Better to install other versions in a directory such as `/usr/local`.

Comment: Everything that I've read while looking for that package indicated that versions of gcc are slotted, meaning you can have multiple versions.

Comment: @ECarterYoung I tried to install the rpm package but also fails, I did not get much information about it, only that "a package that would end the action is not found", more information can be found in a detailed report, but I don't know where it is.

Comment: Can you install VirtualBox?  I have a different approach...

Comment: @ECarterYoung I have already installed.

Comment: OK, now install Gentoo following the [handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?full=1), and set up a Desktop Environment, then follow this [Wiki](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Matlab).  The current stable version of gcc in Gentoos compiler chain is gcc-4.7.3

Comment: @ECarterYoung Thanks, but I decided to use other Matlab scripts (slower) for optimization algorithms that was in mex. I'm not good with Linux yet.